# Tags are appearing in left of the document in embedded Signing using template

Tags: soap, docusignapi

```html
``code`       DocuSignTK.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignTK.Recipient();
        recipient.Email = signer_email; // This person will use embedded signing. If you have his
            // email, supply it. If you don't, use a fake email that includes your
            // ClientUserID. Eg embedded_signer_{ClientUserID}@your_company.com
        recipient.UserName = signer_name;
        recipient.ID = 1;
        recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
        recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
        recipient.RoleName = 'Signer1';        
        // We want this signer to be "captive" so we can use embedded signing with him
        recipient.CaptiveInfo = new DocuSignTK.RecipientCaptiveInfo();
        recipient.CaptiveInfo.ClientUserID = signer_user_id; // Must uniquely identify the             

        // Create the recipient information        
        DocuSignTK.ArrayOfRecipient1 recipients = new DocuSignTK.ArrayOfRecipient1();
        recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignTK.Recipient[1];
        recipients.Recipient[0] = recipient;
        
        DocuSignTK.ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment Roles = new DocuSignTK.ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
        Roles.RoleAssignment = new DocuSignTK.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[1];
        DocuSignTK.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment role = new DocuSignTK.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
        role.RoleName = 'Signer1';
        role.RecipientID = 1;
        Roles.RoleAssignment[0] = role;        
        
        // Create the template reference from a server-side template ID
        DocuSignTK.TemplateReference templateReference = new DocuSignTK.TemplateReference();
        templateReference.Template = 'd0d80082-612b-4a04-b2a1-0672eb720491';
        templateReference.TemplateLocation = 'Server';
        
        
        templateReference.RoleAssignments = Roles; 
        
        // Construct the envelope information
        DocuSignTK.EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new DocuSignTK.EnvelopeInformation();
        envelopeInfo.AccountId = account_Id;
        envelopeInfo.Subject = 'Subject';
        envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = 'Email content';         

        // Make the call
        try {
            //DocuSignTK.EnvelopeStatus result = api_sender.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
            // Create draft with all the template information
            DocuSignTK.ArrayOfTemplateReference TemplateReferenceArray = new DocuSignTK.ArrayOfTemplateReference();
            TemplateReferenceArray.TemplateReference = new DocuSignTK.TemplateReference[1];
            TemplateReferenceArray.TemplateReference[0] = templateReference;
            DocuSignTK.EnvelopeStatus result = api_sender.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates( TemplateReferenceArray, recipients, envelopeInfo, true);
            envelope_id = result.EnvelopeID;
            System.debug('Returned successfully, envelope_id = ' + envelope_id );
        } catch ( CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
            error_code = 'Problem: ' + e;
            error_message = error_code;
        }  `code``
```

I am integrating Docusign for embedded signing. I am using SOAP API and used method *CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates* . Template I created is having some fields/Tabs. But once I open signing url these fields are located on side of the document instead of the location which I sent in template.

I have also assigned Role name for recipient but it is not working. Please help.

[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beirg.png)

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: You are seeing a DocuSign free form signing panel as your code is probably not specifying any tabs. https://www.docusign.com/blog/quick-tip-tuesday-guided-signing-versus-free-form-signing/

Comment: @CodingDawg - Thanks for reply.  I have added code above. My assumption was that CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates  will automatically show Tabs specified on template. If this method doesn't do so then where should I add these tabs. I didn't find any relevent code for this.

Comment: @CodingDawg Can you please help in this? I am not getting clue that how to add these tabs in present structure of request?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I downloaded a template from production and uploaded in sandbox but once I recreated similar template in Sandbox only and used it's template ID in code then it is working perfectly. Apparently, There seems to be some issue with import template utility of Docusign.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the C# code to create an envelope from template using the DocuSign SOAP Api. Documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#DocuSignService%20API%20Overview/Code%20Samples.htm%3FTocPath%3DDocuSign%2520Service%2520API%2520Information%7C_____3)

```
       string apiUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx";
        string accountId = "Enter accountId"; //
        string email = "Enter email";
        string userName = "Enter intergrator key";

        userName += email;
        string _password = "Enter password";
        var apiClient = new DocuSignTK.APIServiceSoapClient("APIServiceSoap", apiUrl);
        apiClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
        apiClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;

        // Construct all the recipient information
        var recipients = new DocuSignTK.Recipient[1];

        recipients[0] = new DocuSignTK.Recipient();
        recipients[0].Email = "recipientone@acme.com";
        recipients[0].UserName = "recipient one";
        recipients[0].Type = DocuSignTK.RecipientTypeCode.Signer;
        recipients[0].ID = "1";
        recipients[0].RoutingOrder = 1;
        recipients[0].RoleName = "Signer1";

        var roles = new DocuSignTK.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[1];
        roles[0] = new DocuSignTK.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
        roles[0].RoleName = recipients[0].RoleName;
        roles[0].RecipientID = recipients[0].ID;

        // Use a server-side template -- you could make more than one of these
        var templateReference = new DocuSignTK.TemplateReference();
        templateReference.TemplateLocation = DocuSignTK.TemplateLocationCode.Server;
        // TODO: replace with template ID from your account
        templateReference.Template = "d0d80082-612b-4a04-b2a1-0672eb720491";
        templateReference.RoleAssignments = roles;

        // Construct the envelope information
        DocuSignTK.EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new DocuSignTK.EnvelopeInformation();
        envelopeInfo.AccountId = " ";
        envelopeInfo.Subject = "create envelope from templates test";
        envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = "testing docusign creation services";

        // Create draft with all the template information
        DocuSignTK.EnvelopeStatus status = apiClient.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(new DocuSignTK.TemplateReference[] { templateReference },
            recipients, envelopeInfo, false);
```